# Recurrence Relation, a question about the relation between $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given the following recurrence relation:

$$A_{n+1} = {1 \over 4(1-A_n) }$$
$$ A_1 = 0 $$
Can I safely assume that if-
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ A_n < 1/2$$ then

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ A_{n+1} < {1\over4(1-{1\over2})} ={1\over2}$$

Thus determining that 
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ A_n < 1/2$$

by induction.

or am I missing a step?

Comment: I think you can prove that $A_n \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: would be easier, but this is the last thing I need to prove, also why I picked $1\over2$.
unfortunately, I have to answer it by order.

Comment: Not easier no (or I'd be glad to see that), but from this result you can get the convergence

Comment: you are right :P
but for some reason it is easier for me to approach problem when I know I need to prove the limit better then prove that it is Continuous (I probably suffer from a lack of experience).

Comment: I see what you mean, but finding the limit and proving that it is indeed its limit are two different things. For instance how would you go on proving that ($A_n$) $\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$? Personally I could use the fact that $(A_n)$ is bounded

Comment: I have so far proven that $\forall n$ $A_n < A_{n+1}$ by induction.
for this fact and the fact that it is bounded it must converge implying it has a limit.
now I can test $|A_n - L|<\epsilon$

Comment: Or you know that L verifies: $L = \frac{1}{4(1-L)} \implies L= \frac{1}{2}$. Of course this can be used only once you have proved that $(A_n)$ converges

Comment: ah since $A_{n+1}$ is the series $A_{n}$ moved by 1 to the left so their limits equal (of course, I must first prove they have a limit)

Comment: Exactly :) , that's often a quick way of finding the limit (doesn't always work though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $A_n<\frac{1}{2}$ we get $4A_n<2$ and this is equivalent to $2<4-4A_n$ and this is equivalent to $\frac{1}{4(1-A_n)}<\frac{1}{2}$ and this is equivalent to $A_{n+1}<\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: beautiful, How do I know to approach it like that? 
is it just by experience?

Comment: i have some students and we solve many mathematical problems to prepare them for the IMO,two of them have got a silver medaille last year in South Africa